# grab exit status from id

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to troubleshoot an odd LDAP replica issue and simply want to identify accounts in /Users that fail with the "id" command.

For example:

```
$ id joe
uid=501(joe) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts)
$ echo $?
0
```

But when an account does not map to an active LDAP account:

```
$ id joesixpack
id: joesixpack: no such user
$ echo $?
1
```

So I'm trying to capture this in a Bash script thusly:

```
for i in `cat $PRUNED_USERS`; do

STATUS=$(id $i | echo $? )

  if [ $STATUS -ne "0" ]; then
       echo $i >> $LOG
    fi
done
```

But this doesn't work, presumably because I've mucked up the `STATUS=$(id $i | echo $? )`

Suggestions?

Your help is much appreciated.

Dan

Comment: Don't pipe the output of id into echo. Do `STATUS=$(id $i; echo $?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of piping the id output through echo you'll probably want to redirect it (and stderr) to /dev/null, so that STATUS only includes the output of `echo $?`:

```
STATUS=$(id $i > /dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?)
```

or instead of using command substitution to get the output of `$?` you could use `$?` directly:

```
for i in `cat $PRUNED_USERS`; do

id $i > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -ne "0" ]; then
       echo $i >> $LOG
    fi
done
```

Comment: @Dan seriously you went with this?

Comment: @StevenPenny yeah, it worked perfectly for my needs. Why do you object?

Comment: @Dan you know what they say, "If you have to ask..."

Answer (score 2):

Your script, reprise

```
while read i
do    
  id "$i" || echo "$i" >> "$LOG"  
done < "$PRUNED_USERS"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are piping the output of `id` into `echo`, but you don't want to echo the output of `id`, just get its return code. So, run `id`, then `echo $?` as two separate commands:

```
STATUS=$(id $i; echo $?)
```

You can suppress "no such user" error messages with:

```
STATUS=$(id $i 2> /dev/null; echo $?)
```

`STATUS` will now hold the return code.